# Difference of two count from differnt table multiple rows and ordered

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this three tables:
up (idcoment, iduser), down(idcoment, iduser) and coment(idcoment (...)).
I need make a query that list the top 10 coments, i.e., the top 10 which have the higher difference on ups minus downs.
Have found some of them but all seems to count just one value instead of all rows...

Comment: And what exactly have you tried and what went wrong with it?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT u.idcoment, 
       d.idcoment, 
       COUNT(u.iduser) - COUNT(d.iduser) diff_up_down
  FROM up u
  FULL OUTER JOIN down d
    ON u.idcoment = d.idcoment
 GROUP BY u.idcoment,
          d.idcoment
 ORDER BY diff_up_down DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You should give more context/explanation for the code.